# MySQL query with a JOIN and WHERE clause not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I'm trying to get a MySQL query to work but keep getting an error. I want to join two tables `tbl_collab` and `tbl.uploads` with a `WHERE` clause but can't figure out what I've got wrong. Thanks.

```
 SELECT tbl_collab.collab_userid, tbl_collab.file, tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id,
    tbl_uploads.id,tbl_uploads.title,
    FROM tbl_uploads
    LEFT JOIN tbl_uploads.id ON tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id
WHERE tbl_collab.collab_userid='2'
```

I get this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tbl_uploads LEFT JOIN tbl_uploads.id ON tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id WHERE ' at line 3

Comment: tbl_uploads.title,  remove this comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your whole syntax after **from** and **left join** are wrong. 
Please update it as per below query.

Try this:

```
SELECT tbl_collab.collab_userid, 
       tbl_collab.file, 
       tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id, 
       tbl_uploads.id, 
       tbl_uploads.title
FROM tbl_collab 
LEFT JOIN tbl_uploads ON tbl_uploads.id = tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id
WHERE tbl_collab.collab_userid='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a comma (,) in your SELECT clause after tbl_uploads_title that should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl_collab.collab_userid, tbl_collab.file, tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id, tbl_uploads.id,tbl_uploads.title FROM tbl_uploads LEFT JOIN tbl_uploads.id ON tbl_collab.tbl_upload_id WHERE tbl_collab.collab_userid='2`
```

Just remove comma before FROM